# How did I lose this hand?

Tags: poker-theory

I was playing in a tournament on bet365,
how did I lose this hand, I would've thought my straight would beat his 3 of a kind,
http://prntscr.com/g7dq4z. 
I just got over my tilt and realised he had a full house, sorry but can you please delte this question.